# Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer’ with actual type ‘m0 Integer’

Tags: haskell

So I'm new to Haskell and I'm writing a basic function which takes 3 integers as arguments and returns how many are equal.

```
howManyEqual :: Int->Int->Int->Integer

howManyEqual x y z =  
        if x == y && x == z then return 3
        else if x == y && x /= z then return 2
        else if x == z && x /= y then return 2
        else if y == z && y /= x then return 2
        else return 0
```

But Im getting the following error:

```
Prelude> :load ex4.1_2.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ex4.1_2.hs, interpreted )

ex4.1_2.hs:11:34:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer’
                with actual type ‘m0 Integer’
    In the expression: return 3
    In the expression:
      if x == y && x == z then
          return 3
      else
          if x == y && x /= z then
              return 2
          else
              if x == z && x /= y then
                  return 2
              else
                  if y == z && y /= x then return 2 else return 0
```

I have same error at `return 2` and `return 0` as well.
What kind of data type is `m0 Integer` and what do I need to do to fix this? 
Any help would be appreciated. Cheers!!

Comment: All of your `/=` checks could be removed. You already know, because the first check failed, that the three numbers are not all equal. Therefore, if (for example) `x == y`, then you already know that `x /= z` and do not need to test it.

Comment: You could also use something more compact by counting equalities regardless of order: `howManyEqual x y z | and xyz = 3 | or xyz = 2 | otherwise = 0 where xyz = [x == y, x == z, y == z]`—that is, if *all* of them compare equal, then 3 are equal; if only *some* of them compare equal, then 2 are equal; otherwise 0 are equal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Delete all the `return` keywords:

```
howManyEqual :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Integer
howManyEqual x y z =  
  if x == y && x == z then 3
  else if x == y && x /= z then 2
  else if x == z && x /= y then 2
  else if y == z && y /= x then 2
  else 0
```

In Haskell, `return` isn't a keyword, but a function with the type `Monad m => a -> m a`. It's mainly used from within code blocks in `do` notation to return values 'wrapped' in a `Monad` instance.

The `howManyEqual` method doesn't return a monadic value, but rather a normal, scalar `Integer`, so `return` isn't required. When you use `return` anyway, the compiler expects the returned value to be part of some `Monad` instance that it calls `m0` in the error message, but since the function has the explicitly declared return type `Integer`, there's no way to reconcile these.

By the way, you can relax the type declaration to:

```
howManyEqual :: (Eq a, Num t) => a -> a -> a -> t
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Also thanks for the type declaration sample, that looks more usable

Answer (score 6):

Some further off topic information about the haskell syntax:

There is nothing wrong with using `else if` in haskell, but it's not common. Haskell supports guards `|` which is some what equivalent to `else if`. However, `if x then y else z` is mosty used for a binary condition, not to gather several different conditions.

`| x == y = 5` = `if x ==y then 5`

Therefore your code could be expressed in the following and more preferable way

```
 howManyEqual :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Integer
 howManyEqual x y z   
   | x == y && x == z = 3
   | x == y && x /= z = 2
   | x == z && x /= y = 2
   | y == z && y /= x = 2
   | otherwise        = 0
```

Comment: Right, I'll keep that in mind. Thanks for the heads up